# i want to include a external php file into html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    include("header.php");
?>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="header.php"></script>

</head>
```

I'm trying to include a PHP (header & footer) file in an HTML file.

The reason it needs to be HTML is this is a content provider that hosts the content and they've put a restriction on the number of characters that can be in the header (as they host it). Any ideas?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: server has to be set to compile php for `html` extension. Can't see why any host would need to restrict `head` tag. That doesn't make any sense. Are you sure they mean `head` tag and not `request header`?

Comment: how m include a php file in javascript...???

Comment: @AnulekhaThakur you want to include PHP in HTML? does not make sense. You most likely askng the wrong question

Answer (score 3):

You can not include php in a html page, as php generates html but html can not generate php. So you can try ajax method to include php instead on page load try calling a javascript function which will call the php file.

Answer (score 0):

window.location.assign("header.php"); 
by this method you can add php file but only in php page..not with html.